# starting with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to download ruby on rails, but i am not understanding what to download here?

http://rubyonrails.org/download

i would like to get ruby on rails and i have windows. which one should i download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instantrails should be what you're looking for.
http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=904

Comment: thanks downloading right now!

Answer (score 1):

Rails guides has articles on getting started
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Use the current version (2.3.x right now)

The book AWDWR from pragmatic programmers is updated for version 2.x of Rails.:
http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails

and RailsCasts has many tutorials:
http://railscasts.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.hackido.com/2009/11/install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-karmic.html

If you have Ubuntu this is good.